# Setting up cgroups with /etc/cgconfig.conf failed with Cgroup, requested group parameter does not exist

Tags: memory, cgroups

I'm looking at getting `cgroups` working on my linux machine and well it's been a pain.

I feel like this should be a lot easier as resource management is pretty key to a healthy desktop environment which is why I'm trying to use it but I've just run into so many problems.

I have a `/etc/cgconfig.conf` file that looks like this:

```
group "chromium_slack" {
    perm {
            admin {
                    uid = "nate";
                    gid = "nate";
            }
            task {
                    uid = "nate";
                    gid = "nate";
            }
    }
    cpu {
            shares="50";
    }
    memory {
            swappiness="60";
            limit_in_bytes="256000000";
    }
}
```

And when I start the `cgconfig` service with this:

```
sudo systemctl start cgconfig.service
```

I get a service status `Cgroup, requested group parameter does not exist` that looks like this:

```
× cgconfig.service - Control Group configuration service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cgconfig.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-12-15 15:17:16 EST; 11min ago
    Process: 9559 ExecStart=/usr/bin/cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf -s 1664 (code=exited, status=95)
   Main PID: 9559 (code=exited, status=95)
        CPU: 8ms

Dec 15 15:17:16 nx systemd[1]: Starting Control Group configuration service...
Dec 15 15:17:16 nx cgconfigparser[9559]: /usr/bin/cgconfigparser; error loading /etc/cgconfig.conf: Cgroup, requested group parameter does not exist
Dec 15 15:17:16 nx systemd[1]: cgconfig.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=95/n/a
Dec 15 15:17:16 nx systemd[1]: cgconfig.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 15 15:17:16 nx systemd[1]: Failed to start Control Group configuration service.
```

But when I try to do this all manually with `cgcreate` like so:

```
sudo cgcreate -a $USER -g memory,cpu:chromium_slack
sudo echo 256M > /sys/fs/cgroup/chromium_slack/memory.limit_in_bytes
```

I get a `permission denied: /sys/fs/cgroup/chromium_slack/memory.limit_in_bytes` error.

So I guess my question is... How the heck do I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You should issue the redirection inside a root shell:

```bash
sudo su - -c 'echo 256M > /sys/fs/cgroup/chromium_slack/memory.limit_in_bytes'
```